# Can a custom button be shared by multiple custom tabs?

Tags: ribbon

I have a custom button (FlyoutAnchor) that is duplicated on every ribbon on every page of our SP 2010 site. It's all working perfectly, but any changes that have to be made must be made 17 times. Is it possible to have a single button that can be referenced by all the tabs, rather than having to explicitly define it on every tab? My assumption after searching online for a while is no, but I thought someone here might have done something similar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use C# Ribbon libraries to generate your Ribbon controls and then you can put the logic in 1 place and call it 17 times. Please take a look at following libraries:

- http://qaspribbon.codeplex.com/
- http://spribbon.codeplex.com/